# Aggregation on Matlab Table

Tags: matlab, aggregation

I have below table in matlab and i want to aggregate this table based on column *name* ,

```
name      nums
'es'     '1,2,3'
'mo'     '4,3,1'
'al'     '2,3,1'
'es'     '40,2,8'
'es'     '1,2,5'
'mo'     '5,2,1'
'ta'     '9,4,2'
'al'     '2,6,1'
...
```

and this my desired output (nums should be unique):

```
name     nums
'es'     '1,2,3,8,40,5'
'mo'     '4,3,1,5,2'
'al'     '2,3,1,6'
'ta'     '9,4,2'
...
```

and this is my code,

```
n,m = size(T);
for i = 1:n
    if ~ismember(name,mynewtab)
         mynewtab.input(i).nums = mynewtab.input(i).nums + nums;
    else
         mynewtab.input(i).nums = mynewtab.input(i).nums + nums;
         mynewtab.input(i).name = name;
    end
end
```

but this code has some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This code has some errors" is not a great problem statement, you should start with the fact that `+` is not defined like you think for character arrays.

This code using `strjoin` and `unique` should do what you want....

```
uNames = unique(tbl.name);    % Get unique names
c = cell( numel(uNames), 2 ); % Set up output (we'll turn this into a table later)
for ii = 1:numel(uNames)
    c{ii,1} = uNames{ii}; % Assign the name to 1st column
    % Join all strings in the 'nums' column, with a comma between them, when the 
    % value in the names column is equal to uNames{ii}
    c{ii,2} = strjoin( tbl.nums( strcmp( tbl.name, uNames{ii} ) ).', ',' );
end

tblOut = cell2table( c, 'VariableNames', {'name','nums'} );
```

If you want to only have unique elements from the strings, you'll have to use `strsplit` to split on the commas, and then join together after a call to `unique`... Replace the `c{ii,2} = ...` line with the following:

```
vals = tbl.nums( strcmp( tbl.name, uNames{ii} ) ).';       % Get nums for this name
vals = cellfun( @(str)strsplit(str,','), vals, 'uni', 0 ); % Split all on ','
% Join the list of unique values back together. 
% Could use 'stable' argument of unique for order preservation.
c{ii,2} = strjoin( unique( [vals{:}] ), ',' );
```

**Note:** this would all be a lot easier if you stored the list of numbers as an array of actual numbers, rather than a character array!

Comment: Does `accumarray` not work on tables? It might let you get rid of the loop

Comment: @Dan You could probably use `varfun` or `splitapply` to remove the loop, but I can't imagine this loop in inherently slow, I just prioritised clarity.

Comment: If splitapply is like groupby, I would argue that it is more clear than a loop

Comment: @Dan feel free to write an answer you feel is clearer

Comment: @Wolfie I don't have MATLAB or I'd try out splitapply :(